# Weird error when deploying with pm2 and WSL2

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pm2, wsl-2

I have a deploy.sh script which looks like this:

`ssh -t <name> -<port> 'cd <foldername>; git pull; yarn build <appname>; pm2 restart <appname> --update-env'`

It works perfectly when I'm using Windows Powershell but for some reason, it fails if I use my WSL terminal. It completes all stages of the script up until `pm2 restart` part, at this point   `error: unknown option --update-env` appears, ssh connection closes and I have to manually connect to ssh server and restart pm2.

I'm not sure if there is a problem with my wsl or with pm2 but since '--update-env' is a pm2 option I guess it is pm2.

I'm using pm2 version 4.5.6

PSVersion 5.1.19041.1237

WSL2 Ubuntu-20.04.2 LTS

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds You are right! What should I do to make sure the script runs on a remote machine only?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I actually misread your comment. I have singular quotes same as your last comment.

Comment: And no special characters in the <appname> that could be handled differently between PowerShell and Bash?  I'm suspecting a difference between the way that PowerShell and WSL are passing this, rather than a problem with pm2.  Can you add (a) your shell (I'm assuming Bash), (2) Your WSL distribution/release to your question?  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I also thought about that however I don't really know how to fix it. ps. I edited my question and added more info

Comment: I'm not yet sure how to fix it either, but let's see if we can get to the root cause.  Let's start with trying to get an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Does it happen if you *just* do `ssh -t <name> -<port> 'pm2 restart <appname> --update-env'` (taking out the other commands)?  Is the remote host a Linux host?  If so, then what happens if you try to `ssh` to the server and then `ssh -t localhost 'pm2 restart <appname> --update-env'`?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yup, remote host is a centos 7. If I remove all part of the script and just do `ssh -t <name> -<port> 'pm2 restart <appname> --update-env'` as you said it works fine, no error.

Comment: Ok, a few more things to try to isolate this.  First, like before, on the host, run the full `ssh` line, but against localhost (e.g. `ssh -t localhost -<port> 'cd <foldername>; git pull; yarn build <appname>; pm2 restart <appname> --update-env'.  If that fails, then the difference is just between PowerShell and Linux/Bash.  If that succeeds, then we can zero in on your local WSL config some more.

Comment: Next, (hopefully I craft this line correctly), `ssh -t -o "RemoteCommand=bash --noprofile --norc -c 'cd <foldername>; git pull; yarn build <appname>; pm2 restart <appname> --update-env'" <name> -<port>`

Comment: And perhaps a stupid question, but why do you need the `-t` to force a pseudo-terminal?  Is there something interactive in the yarn build?

Comment: As for your other comments, I'll try everything you suggested after work. Thanks for being so patient!

Comment: Sure thing!  It may be a bit more tenancy and curiosity than patience :-).  That said, we've reached the end of "Stack's patience" with comments, so I'm going to move this to chat.  Note that, in my experience, we *really* do need to remember to tag each other in replies, otherwise it gets really hard to remember to check the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237423/discussion-between-notthedr01ds-and-pcpbiscuit).